# Microsoft Excel - Conditional Formatting to match cell in column to cell in same row of different column

Tags: excel, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have a workbook created in Excel 2013 that every engineer at my job has to use to check data that was input into a system. We are able to export the files into XLS, and I created a macro to pull all the data and conditional formatting to display "errors" that need to be fixed.

We are in the process of versioning the workbook, and to do so I am trying to get some more complicated formulas out there to check the data. There are several columns that need to be cross checked in one check, because they should match. This means i need a formatting rule to look in any given cell in a column, and check other cells in the SAME ROW, but DIFFERENT COLUMN, and make sure they match..

For example:
Column A is Label ID Text, and in this case it says 1 - 1.5" HDPE.
Column B is the Duct Count, which is 1
Column C is the Duct Size, which is 1.5"
and Column D is the Duct Type, which is HDPE.

I the Label ID text to take the 3 separate parts of the string, and match it to other columns. If it doesn't it highlights the column B-D that doesn't match. I manually created an example of what I need it to do.

Example:

[image: Example:]

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have never tried to create a code that looks at a string of text before. I checked for other similar questions on various forums for an answer, and nothing really pointed me to where I wanted to go. I apologize for asking the question without showing an attempt. Every other CF on the page is an ISBLANK, Cell Contains Value, or I have it refer to the first worksheet where we fill in blanket info (if it doesnt match it highlights)

Comment: The most complex conditional formatting formula we have on the entire workbook is "=Formulas!$B$9," which is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this involves working with strings, specifically the functions `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `MID`, and also being mindful of how you're comparing items.

It all involves being meticulous in how you're separating the values from the string in your first column. In order to test all your function, start using empty cells to slowly build up the formulas to assemble the overall logic.

In figuring out your duct count, you can see you want "the number to the left of the dash character". So you'll start this way...

```
=FIND("-",A2)
```

You only want the characters to the left of the dash, so use the `LEFT` function

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2))
```

Which returns a value of `1 -`, but you don't want to include the dash, so subtract one.

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)
```

Now if you compare this value to your Duct Count in column B, you'll get

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2))=B2
```

Which gives a value of `FALSE`. This is because the result of the `LEFT` function you built is a string "1 " and not a number. So use another function to convert it to a number

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1))=B2
```

Now you get the correct result of `TRUE`.

So highlight cells B2:B5 and select Conditional Formatting-->New Rule. Then choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Then type in your formula (the whole =NUMBERVALUE thing) and select your format. And you're done with that column.

Continue to work out how to separate the values for the other columns. If you have more questions we can help.

Comment: That work exactly how I need it to for with a specific row! Now, the issue is, can that be done for an entire column, no matter what cell number it is? Like, I need all of A to check with all of B-D, that's at a dynamic range. The exports will pull a new number of features every time, and i need it to check all of them no matter what. Every other conditional formatting rule wasn't as complex as this one though. It was just ISBLANK, or Cell Value Contains type formulas. I will upvote your answer

Comment: Even though the formula uses A2 and B2, if you apply it to all of column B it will work (Excel automatically substitutes the appropriate row numbers in the formula). For the other columns, just take it step by step and piece out how to extract and compare the appropriate string values.

Comment: I was able to make it work! Thanks a ton, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear any existing CF from ColumnsB:D, select them and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=NOT(OR(B1=--LEFT($A1,FIND("-",$A1)-2),B1=MID($A1,FIND("-",$A1)+2,FIND("-",$A1)+1),B1=MID($A1,FIND("""",$A1)+2,LEN($A1))))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: Crazy how complicated the formula is, but it makes sense since it has to find the specific pieces in a string of text. Thanks for your response!